# Performance issue with C# Auto Mapper

Tags: c#

I have recently faced with a problem with C# AutoMapper performance (Specially with bigger collections), What is the best alternative to C# AutoMapper?

Comment: Maybe show some code that demostrates the problem? Someone might have a solution or based on your use-case present a different implementation that might involve another library...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to AutoMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052002/alternatives-to-automapper)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I also wanted to perform automatic one-to-one object mapping but had the same performance issue with AutoMapper when I wanted to deal with lots of complex objects during execution. That why I wrote a T4 generator to automatically generate static mapping at pre-build.
It's not as flexible as AutoMapper (so far, it only works with strict one-to-one definitions) but the runtime performance is equivalent to manually written mappers.

It's called **oMapGen** and I just published it on [CodePlex](https://omapgen.codeplex.com/) and as a NuGet package, so don't hesitate to try it and see if it fits in your projects. I may extend it in the future to make it more customizable.

Answer (score 3):

Never had issues with AutoMapper, however I'm hearing pretty good stuff about [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/), it should be a solid alternative.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663577/automapper-vs-valueinjecter) is a good comparison between both, might be helpful.